# UK demographic data at full or outer postcode level

Tags: data-request, uk, demographics, postal-code

Is anyone aware of any open UK demographic data (England would be sufficient) at full or out postcode level?

Comment: What do you mean by "outer postcode"? Postcode area, district, sector, something else? ONS have demographics by Lower Super Output Area: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/datasets/lowersuperoutputareamidyearpopulationestimates

Comment: Outer postcodes are the first 2-4 characters.

Comment: That part of the postcode is also known as the postcode district, outbound code, or outcode. I'm not aware of a dataset that gives you exactly what you need, but ONS has the demographic data by LSOA, and both postcode district and LSOA boundaries are available, so if you are handy with GIS you could approximate the demographics for postcode district. Happy to flesh this out in an answer if that helps. You could also contact the ONS directly and see if they have the data you need.

Comment: Some data for England: https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/transparencyandgovernance/freedomofinformationfoi/ukpopulationbypostcode

Comment: Thanks England would actually be sufficient. Populations size is a good start but debt levels, unemployment rates etc would be needed too.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/english-indices-of-deprivation-2015](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/english-indices-of-deprivation-2015)

Comment: Did anyone figure out where to get this information? Looking for a link to a csv dump. Ether by year or whatever. outercode,count usually gov.uk is pretty good about data but this one is not great so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sees like this https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/census/2011/postcode_headcounts_and_household_estimates

```
wget https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/output/census/2011/Postcode_Estimates_Table_1.csv 

$ head Postcode_Estimates_Table_1.csv 
"Postcode","Total","Males","Females","Occupied_Households"
"AL1 1AG",14,6,8,6
"AL1 1AJ",124,60,64,51
"AL1 1AR",32,17,15,17
"AL1 1AS",34,17,17,13
"AL1 1BH",52,15,37,41
"AL1 1BX",54,26,28,19
"AL1 1BY",18,9,9,5
"AL1 1BZ",18,11,7,12
"AL1 1DG",24,10,14,8
```